# How to reference a file from any directory

Tags: java, shell, path, cygwin

I'm having the following situation.

I have a java programm packed in a jar file. If I call `java -jar myProgramm.jar` everything is working fine. The file is reading some values from **build.xml** (ant file). This file is in the same directory where myProgramm.jar is located.
In our company we wrap everything in shell scripts to have a uninfied way to call our scripts.

So my shell script myProgrammWrapper.sh looks like this:

```
    #!bin/bash
java -jar $(cygpath -w ~/path/to/tools/myProgramm.jar) "$@"
```

The cygpath command is there because the sh is executed within cygwin and otherwise the path would not be found.
The"$@" passes the arguments to the program.

**Following is the problem:**

Our cygwin environment has been setup in a way that I can call myProgrammWrapper.sh from every directory. But of course when I call it from any random location, the build.xml is not found.

Is there a way to reference the **build.xml** in the shell script. It is located in `~/path/to/tools/` ?

First I was thinking about copying the build file to the current directory and deleting it afterwards. This is working fine but has one fundamental flaw. We are working a lot with ant and have build.xml files. So if someone would execute myProgrammWrapper.sh in a directory where there is already a build.xml file. It would be overwritten.

Maybe the problem can be tackled from the Java side. Any ideas and input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the Bash script change the working directory to where the XML file is contained?

Try:

`(cd $(cygpath -w ~/path/to/tools/) && java -jar $(cygpath -w ~/path/to/tools/myProgramm.jar) "$@")`

Comment: this is a good idea. There is one additional problem.
The program is creating some output files. And it is expected to find them in the directory from where the myProgramWrapper.sh is called.

Is there a way to add that functionality in the bash script?

Comment: @elToro Who is expecting the output files to be in the directory from which you launched `myProgramWrapper.sh`? In the Bash script, can you not just `mv` the output files to wherever the script was called from?

Comment: Also a good idea.
I did not mention that the program is called like this:
myProgramWrapper.sh -p com.some.package
Where "com.some.package" is free to the person calling the program. So I would need to move that directory. We would need to get that paramter in the bash script and use provide it to mv command. Is that doable?

Comment: @elToro Sorry, it's hard to understand what you're trying to say in that last comment.

Comment: Sorry for that :-) Let me try again.
myProgram.jar is creating java class files. These class files are included into existing java projects. As a convenience function the user is able to specify the package-name when running myProgram.jar.
Example:
myProgramWrapper.sh -p my.package.name

When the class files are created, they are created in that package structure, which translates to the folders created.
In the above example we would get the folder structure "my/package/name/". The generated class files will be located here. Now we need to move the whole folder-structure including the files.

Comment: @elToro In that case you could use `mv -r` to move this whole class folder structure. But this is an ugly way to solve this problem: the clean way is for your myProgramm.jar program to output to whichever directory it was called from. Edit your myProgramm to take a `-x` switch that will take an XML file. Then in your Bash script just run `myProgram.jar -x /path/to/build.xml`, without changing current working directory.

Comment: that is definitly an option. Maybe it is not the most userfriendly one, but it will work.
Thank you for taking the time to look into this.